# How to use ext3 filesystem for running application in OpenEBS?

Tags: openebs

How to use ext3 supported filesystem in OpenEBS volume? I am running an application which need ext3 filesystem. 
I know that OpenEBS is running with ext4 filesystem by default. But how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the information from the OpenEBS documentation

**----**

OpenEBS supports ext3,ext4 and XFS file systems. By default, it comes with ext4 file system for the mounted volumes. Some applications require using the XFS as file system. The policy to specify XFS as the file system, you must add `openebs.io/fstype: "xfs"` under section `annotations:`

**----**

Following is a sample storage class for application which need to be run on ext3. Similar way I can change the FSType to ext3.
Below is the sample StorageClass YAML I have used for using ext3 filesystem.

```
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
   name: openebs-ext3
   annotations:
    openebs.io/cas-type: jiva
    cas.openebs.io/config: |
      - name: ControllerImage
        value: openebs/jiva:0.8.0
      - name: ReplicaImage
        value: openebs/jiva:0.8.0
      - name: VolumeMonitorImage
        value: openebs/m-exporter:0.8.0
      - name: ReplicaCount
        value: "1"
      - name: StoragePool
        value: default
      - name: FSType
        value: "ext3"
      #- name: TargetResourceLimits
      #  value: |-
      #      memory: 1Gi
      #      cpu: 100m
      #- name: AuxResourceLimits
      #  value: |-
      #      memory: 0.5Gi
      #      cpu: 50m
      #- name: ReplicaResourceLimits
      #  value: |-
      #      memory: 2Gi
provisioner: openebs.io/provisioner-iscsi
reclaimPolicy: Delete
```